# Crashed: PHTFlatFilePhenotype MLKITx_BuildData::BaselineChangelistAsInt()

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

We're running a hybrid Flutter/native iOS app. Since a release we did at the start of October we've started getting a growing number of these crashes, seemingly only affecting iOS 12 devices, and almost always around 50 seconds after the app launches:

```
Crashed: PHTFlatFilePhenotype
0  <App name>                 0x104d6ac MLKITx_BuildData::BaselineChangelistAsInt() + 71964
1  <App name>                 0x1012078 __82-[MLKITx_PHTFlatFilePhenotype registerPackage:version:logSources:params:callback:]_block_invoke.192 + 4329873528
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x5fa38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x607d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x9324 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x9e40 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x124ac _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xc114 _pthread_wqthread + 304
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xecd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

The first release that these started happening in was using Flutter 3.10.0, and a more recent update that still has the problem is on the more recent Flutter 3.13.9.

Because it seems to be coming from within iOS itself (MLKit? Machine Learning kit? - we don't consciously use this at all in our app) it's hard to know where to look for a cause... iOS 12 is the latest version that various devices are able to update to, so just telling the user to update iOS isn't an option. But presumably it *is* related to something we've changed in our code, because it started so suddenly after our app update - I just can't see any obvious causes by looking at the diffs.

Has anybody else experienced this, and if so, did you manage to find the cause?

Our app does use Firebase as well.

Comment: May I know the firebase version that you are using ? @andygeers

Comment: @SwaminathanV It's pretty ancient (FirebaseCore is 8.15.0) - we've had real trouble upgrading those dependencies, getting all manner of compilation issues

Comment: I have encountered this problem recently, and I am confident that it's not related to Flutter. We have been using Flutter 3.10.x since day one, and we haven't faced any issues so far. I compared the version between the one that doesn't have a problem and the one that does. I didn't upgrade any libraries; all Firebase libraries remain the same as the non-crash version. However, I noticed that the issue occurs only on iPhone 6 and 6s

Answer (score 1):

After conducting thorough investigation and trial and error, I was unable to identify the root cause of the issue. Reverting to the version I deployed, which had the same code and dependencies, and testing on both production and non-production versions with different assets, including Firebase and other SDKs, did not result in a crash on my iPhone 6. However, when I returned to the same code deployed earlier this month, it crashed with an ML Kit error.

Even though I upgraded Flutter to the latest version (3.16.5), I don't see any issue as well.

In my case, the problem seemed to have resolved itself. I suspect this might be related to updating Xcode and MacOS since my last build. In your situation, you could try updating Xcode and MacOS to the latest versions and see if it resolves the issue for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds a bit interesting. Can I clarify though- it says when you upgraded Flutter you didn't see the issue? So do you think upgrading Flutter solved it? Or do you mean with the *old* code, upgrading Flutter didn't break it? With the *new* code, does the issue go away with latest Xcode/macOS? Perhaps you could just clear up some of those ambiguities in your answer?

Comment: In my case, just upgrade Xcode and macOS to be the latest